# Will Active Record help me concatenate two strings in a database-neutral way?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, activerecord

I'm adding SQLite support to a Rails 2.3 codebase designed for MySQL.

Most of the changes so far have been fairly straightforward, but I've now found some examples like the following code:

```
SomeModel.find(:first,
  :conditions => ["? LIKE CONCAT(some_attribute, '%')", a_variable]
)
```

I can't just use the ANSI concatenation operator because the double-pipes mean something else to MySQL. That is to say, the following code passes on SQLite3 but fails on MySQL:

```
SomeModel.find(:first,
  :conditions => ["? LIKE some_attribute || '%')", a_variable]
)
```

Is there something I cleaner I can do than some kind of `case database_adapter when :mysql ...`?

Answer (score 3):

My kinda-ugly solution:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class.concat_sql("firstname", "' '", "lastname")

# config/initializers/active_record_hacks.rb
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter
  def self.concat_sql(*values)
    "CONCAT(#{values * ', '})"
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  def self.concat_sql(*values)
    values * " || "
  end
end
```